# I want to give same value on Javascript tag

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf and javascript.

I need to give same value like this `data-value = ""`

How can I give the same value

```
         , createdCell: function(value, data) {
              return '<div class="date-box flex flex-vc mt mr10">' +
                      ' <div class="date flex flex-vc">' +
                      '   <input type="text" name="stage2" class="datepicker" data-vlaue="'+ (value == null) ? '' : new Date(value).format('yyyy-MM-dd') +'">' +
                      ' </div>' +
                     '</div>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve it using thymeleaf try following

```html
<input th:attr="data-value=${value ? new java.util.Date(value).format('yyyy-mm-dd') : ''}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the type of input to "date" and then set value normally.

```html
<input type="date" id="myDate" />

<input type="date" th:value="${myDate}"/>
```